# Blank with foreach() argument must be of type array | object, string given in

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php $wheretowatch = get_field('wheretowatch'); ?>
<?php foreach($wheretowatch as $wheretowatch):?>
    <div class="movies-series-tvshow-wheretowatch">
            <div class="movies-series-tvshow-wheretowatch-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($wheretowatch->ID);?>"> <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($wheretowatch->ID, 'thumbnail');?>"></a>
            </div>
        
            <div class="movies-series-tvshow-wheretowatch-title">
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($wheretowatch->ID);?>"><h6><?php echo $wheretowatch->post_title;?></h6></a>
            </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

i have an error when not putting a value in relationship field is there an error how to give an echo when the condition is not met?

Comment: if this is a relationship field - I would follow the documentation on relationship fields, and use if have_rows, while have_rows etc.

Comment: Did you look at the docs? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the field is empty and only loop if there is a value.

```
$wheretowatch = get_field('wheretowatch');

if (!empty($wheretowatch)):
    foreach (...) {}
else:
    echo 'your message';
endif;
```